# List SUM Data from MySQL server within a time interval

Tags: mysql, sql

I've a table called `ch6` and it has fields like:

```
id, daytime, tout, tloss.. etc. 
daytime is DATETIME , tout and tloss are integer
```

Now, I want to retrieve and list sum of `tloss` and `tout` for each of the date in table like this

```
date || sum(tout) for certain interval || sum(tloss) for certain interval
```

I'm facing some problem with the interval is up to the next day

ex:

```
20-2-2014 || (sum of tout from 8:00pm to 8:00am the next day) || (sum of tloss between 8:00pm to 8:00am the next day)
```

What is the solution? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like below

```
SELECT daytime , SUM(tout) AS total_tout , SUM(tloss) as total_loss 
FROM ch6 
WHERE daytime 
BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE() + INTERVAL 20 HOUR AND CURRENT_DATE() + INTERVAL 32 HOUR
GROUP BY daytime;
```

Comment: Hi Abdul thanks for the fast reply. Tried your query but its listing down all tout and tloss for current date and its not summed. what i really want is sum(tout) and sum(tloss) for each of the date in table with interval as in question above.